# setState Which grammar is closer to clean code?

Tags: reactjs

```
const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
const [password, setPassword] = useState('');

const handleChangeEmail = (e) => setEmail(e.target.value);
const handleChangePasswrod = (e) => setPassword(e.target.value);

vs 

const [userInfo, setUserInfo] = useState({email: '', password:''});

const handleChangeUserInfo = (e) => {
  const {name, value} = e.target;
  setUserInfo(prev => {...prev, ...{[name]:value}})
}
```

I think the code below will be better if there is more information about userinfo, but what do you think?

Comment: I think that this is a personal preference but yes if you do have multiple fields then the code below looks cleaner and not cluttered with multiple state variables.

Answer (score 0):

```
const [user,setUser] = useState()

function handleChange(e) {
 setUser({...user,[e.target.name]:e.target.value})
}

<input name="email" onChange={(e) => handleChange(e)} />
```